# Can't inherit from constructor in c++

Tags: c++

I have  problem is in inheriting from the template class ! the structor is wrong But I can't get where .
the source code

```
#include "waitingCustomerQueueType.h"

waitingCustomerQueueType::waitingCustomerQueueType(int taille): 
QueType<JobType>QueType(taille)
{
//ctor
}
```

The error message

```
Expected ( before QueType
Expected { before QueType
expected constructor , destructor or type conversion before { Token
```

QueType is a template class that has this constructor

template

```
QueType<ItemType>::QueType(int max)
{

}
```

Could you please help me on fixing the error Thank you

Comment: Please post a [mcve] not code fragments.

Comment: Change the `QueType<JobType>QueType` nonsense into `QueType<JobType>`

Answer (score 0):

In the `waitingCustomerQueueType` constructor, change  this:

```
QueType<JobType>QueType(taille)
```

To this:

```
QueType<JobType>(taille)
```